# Open set in a subset of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,d) $ be a metric space. Let $A \subseteq Y \subseteq X$ where $(Y, d_y)$ is the metric space induced by the restriction of metric $d$ to $Y$. Now, I am trying to prove the following theorem:

$A$ is said to be open in $Y$ if and only if there exists an open set $G \in X$ such that $A = G \cap Y$.

I can see that proving ($\impliedby$) is trivial since we know that finite intersection of open sets is open.
I would like some help to prove the other direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The restriction referred to here is restricting the domain of the metric $d_y$ to be $Y$ x $Y$. I don't see how this is helpful! Could you be more specific? @a-plate-of-momos

Comment: Oops I was confused. Sorry.

Comment: I think the issue is that mentioned "said to be open" but openness can be defined without that condition you said right? A is open if for each point there is a ball of some size greater than zero for each point.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954138/proof-about-a-subset-of-a-metric-space?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I may try to give you a hint:

Recall that open sets in a metric space are open balls with respect to the given metric.

So let $A$ be an open in $Y$. Since $A \subseteq Y \subseteq X$, there is a open ball or a union of open balls in $X$ containing $A$. Thus, there is $G$ open in $X$ so that $A \subseteq G$.